# Frontend Ajax call not working using wp_ajax, wp_enqueue_script and wp_localize_script

Tags: plugin-development, ajax

I think i've almost got my head around this ajax is Wordpress business, thoroughly ejoying learning it but i'm now totally stumped.

First up is the nasty bits! I have these in my main plugin file:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'function', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'function.js', array( 'jquery', 'json2' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'function', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion');
```

Here is what's is function.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#convert").click(function () {
                var from = $("#from").val();
                var to = $("#to").val();
                var amount = $("#amount").val();

    //Make data string
     var dataString = "amount=" + amount + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           action: pfxconversion,
           url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
           data: dataString,
           success: function(data){

           $('#result').show();

            //Put received response into result div
            $('#result').html(data);
           }
         });
    });
});
```

and here is the function that I know works perfectly outside of Wordpress.

```
function pfxconversion () {
//Get Posted data
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];

//make string to be put in API
$string = "1".$from."=?".$to;

//Call Google API
$google_url = "http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=".$string;

//Get and Store API results into a variable
$result = file_get_contents($google_url);

//Explode result to convert into an array
$result = explode('"', $result);

################################
# Right Hand Side
################################
$converted_amount = explode(' ', $result[3]);
$conversion = $converted_amount[0];
$conversion = $conversion * $amount;
$conversion = round($conversion, 2);

//Get text for converted currency
$rhs_text = ucwords(str_replace($converted_amount[0],"",$result[3]));

//Make right hand side string
$rhs = $conversion.$rhs_text;

################################
# Left Hand Side
################################
$google_lhs = explode(' ', $result[1]);
$from_amount = $google_lhs[0];

//Get text for converted from currency
$from_text = ucwords(str_replace($from_amount,"",$result[1]));

//Make left hand side string
$lhs = $amount." ".$from_text;

################################
# Make the result
################################

echo $lhs." = ".$rhs;exit;
}
```

The problem is I don't get the result from my function / ajax request printed out in the #result div

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit** I'm now getting a -1 value in #result, after changed my js from $ to jQuery - Firebug was reporting an error ($ is not a function).

**Edit 2** I'm pretty certain I have the action right now but i'm still getting an output in #result of -1:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery("#convert").click(function () {
                var from = jQuery("#from").val();
                var to = jQuery("#to").val();
                var amount = jQuery("#amount").val();

    //Make data string
     var dataString = "amount=" + amount + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;

         jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
           data: "action=pfxconversion"&dataString, 
           success: function(data){
           jQuery('#result').show();

            //Put received response into result div
            jQuery('#result').html(data);
           }
         });
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the AJAX call using Firebug, Chrome, etc? Are the headers being sent like intended? What kind of response do you get from the function? Also, shouldn't "action" from the $.ajax call be inside the dataString? Are you sure it's being sent to your ajax URL? WordPress will give a "0" response if the action is not set or not valid...

Comment: Hi Tomas, thanks for your response, Wordpress is indeed returning a "0". I'm pretty certain the action is in the correct place, but i may be wrong?

Comment: What happens if you add `add_action('wp_ajax_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion');` right after the `no_priv` action? What if you change all the `$` in your js to `jQuery`?

Comment: I managed to get a "-1" response (was "0" before) after changing $ to jQuery (i made an edit before you mentioned it :p ) adding the other action right after it still produces -1, so at least I know its working in a fashion. The problem appears to be my action in function.js - I think it needs adding to the data: but i'm not 100% sure how to add a var + the action

Comment: From the edits you've made, you're probably requesting a "pfxconversionamount" action. Perhaps you're missing a "&" after "action=pfxconversion"? Everything else seems OK to me.

Comment: No, that didn't work either. There is still amiss with the action i think....I can see this one is going to keep me up all night :-)

Comment: `data: "action=pfxconversion"&dataString, `, maybe try `data: "action=pfxconversion&" + dataString, `?

Comment: Thanks Jared but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the top of your generated HTML source code. Are you seeing something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var MyAjax = {"ajaxurl":"http:\/\/localboast\/home\/wp2\/wp-admin\/admin-ajax.php"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

wp_localize_script now escapes whatever you pass into it. So that the problem I have.

Comment: Interesting, certainly looks to be a problem, that is what i see in the source!

Answer (score 2):

In your jQuery, maybe try something like this:

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {

    jQuery( "#convert" ).click( function() {
        var from = jQuery( "#from" ).val();
        var to = jQuery( "#to" ).val();
        var amount = jQuery( "#amount" ).val();

        //Make data string
        var dataString = "amount=" + amount + "&from=" + from + "&to=" + to;

        jQuery.post( MyAjax.ajaxurl, {
            action: 'pfxconversion',
            data: dataString
        }, function( data ) {

            if( data.response === 'success' ) {

                // Success
                jQuery( '#result' ).show();

                //Put received response into result div
                jQuery( '#result' ).html( data.html );

            } else {

                // Failure

            }

        } );
    } );
} );
```

The PHP function that this AJAX call sends data to and receives data from should send back a **JSON encoded array** and also I added in a 'success' and 'failure' variable called `response`, might as well send this back with your AJAX call for better accuracy.

Your JSON encoded array that you send back to the AJAX should look something like this:

```
$response = json_encode( array( 'response' => 'success', 'html' => 'some value' ) );
echo $response;
exit; // This is needed to send back properly
```

**Edit**

Based on your example, you should change this line:

```
echo $lhs." = ".$rhs;exit;
```

to something like

```
echo json_encode( array( 'html' => $lhs." = ".$rhs, 'response' => 'success' ) ); exit;
```

And then you could access it with `data.html` in your AJAX function.

**Edit 2**

On another note, you need to enqueue your scripts in the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook like below. You would remove these codes and re-place them in your plugin like this (also changed the location of the file to use `plugins_url()`):

```
function enqueue_some_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'json2' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' ); // If not loaded in your theme already, wouldn't hurt here though I don't think!

    wp_enqueue_script( 'function', plugins_url( 'function.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery', 'json2' ) );
    wp_localize_script( 'function', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_some_scripts' );
```

Comment: Thanks mate but changing the js to your example hits me back with a 0 where as i was at least getting a -1 before. However i'm not sure what you mean with that last part, json_encode, I'll go look it up as i guess i'm missing something. Thanks for your help

Comment: I added jQuery( '#result' ).html( 'failed' ); to the else statement and as i expected it is coming back as failed!

Comment: @Danny See my edit I explain how you can use the `json_encode` to send variables back in your example.

Comment: Thanks for that, I was almost there before you spoon fed me the answer :p Much appreciated. The bad news is i'm still getting "failed"! In which case i'm convinced the problem lies in here somewhere: wp_enqueue_script( 'function', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'function.js', array( 'jquery', 'json2' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'function', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_pfxconversion', 'pfxconversion');

Comment: Which hook are you running `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_localize_script` on or are they not hooked to any action?

Comment: The only place they are been used is what I have posted right there, judging by your comment i guess i'm missing something? :-) I spent a good couple of hours on that little bit so i was pretty confident i got it right.

Comment: See my edit. :)

Comment: If you are still getting 'failed' and you are using the `data.response` variable, you need to make sure you are echoing the `response` variable with your JSON encoded array. I updated my answer with it added in there (my first edit).

Comment: Thanks once again, after adding the new enqueue function it's not running at all, i'm gonna have a bash again tomorrow with fresh eyes, so tired now. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep an eye on the JavaScript console for errors, maybe you are enqueueing jQuery twice? I'm not completely sure how that works but try commenting out `wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );` -- not sure if that is the issue but like I said check the JavaScript console. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly late answer, but in WP you need to `die()` at the end of your php AJAX function. If you don't die you get that `0` response.  Check out the wp-admin/admin-ajax.php file.